# Error: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Tags: python, opencv, rgb, numpy-ndarray, hsv

i'm working on numpt matrix, i can create an HSV image and after convert it in RGB image. i create a matrix HSV with:
`matrix_=np.zeros([3, H-kernel+1, W-kernel+1], dtype=np.float32)`

after i have filled it with magnitudes, 255, theta of angle, to each value:
`matrix_[:, row, column]=np.array([th, 255, mag])`
finally i convert it with:
`cv2.cvtColor(matrix_, matrix_, cv2.COLOR_HSV2RGB)`

but it throws: "`TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`" in line of cv2.cvtColor. why? where i wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing the order of the arguments.

See documentation of [cvtColor](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor):

> Python: cv2.cvtColor(src, code[, dst[, dstCn]]) → dst

As you can see the destination matrix is the third argument.
The `code` is the second argument.
The `code` should be scalar, but you are passing `matrix_` as second argument, so you are getting the error:
`"TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars"`.

For avoiding the error, you may use:

```
cv2.cvtColor(matrix_, cv2.COLOR_HSV2RGB, matrix_)
```

You better use the return value (the syntax is more clear):

```
matrix_ = cv2.cvtColor(matrix_, cv2.COLOR_HSV2RGB)
```

---

Now there is another exception: `"Invalid number of channels in input image"`.

You have set the matrix shape wrong:

Instead of `matrix_=np.zeros([3, H-kernel+1, W-kernel+1], dtype=np.float32)`, it should be:

```
matrix_=np.zeros([H-kernel+1, W-kernel+1, 3], dtype=np.float32)
```

---

The syntax `matrix_[:, row, column]=np.array([th, 255, mag])` looks weird.
You didn't post the values of `row`, `column`, `th` and `mag`.
I can't say if it is correct or not.
I must assume it is out of the scope of your question...

Comment: row and column are int, i use them to iterate on matrix, th and mag are float. what's wrong?

Comment: I didn't say it's wrong, it's just weird... I used to begin with RGB, convert from RGB to HSV, apply some processing in HSV color space, and convert back to RGB.

Comment: I think it should be `[th, 1, mag]` instead of `[th, 255, mag]`. You intention is to modify a single pixel right?